# Is there any method print dictionary with all information from object?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

I have an object in Python. During analyzing of dataset I create sevral objects and save it in dictionary based on objectID

```py
class TrackableObject:
    def __init__(self, objectID, centroid, timestart, timeend):
    # store the object ID, then initialize a list of centroids
    # using the current centroid
        self.objectID = objectID
        self.centroids = [centroid]
        self.timestart = timestart
        self.timeend = timeend

    #initialize a boolean used to indicate if the object has
    # already been counted or not
        self.counted = False
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.objectID, self.timestart, self.timeend)
```

```py
import pprint 
dictionary[objectID] = object 
pprint.pprint(dictionary)
```

when I print the final dictionary I receive:

```
{0: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee54b70>,
 1: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f6458857668>,
 2: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee54c50>,
 3: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee54be0>,
 4: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee54c18>,
 5: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee70588>,
 6: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee70438>,
 7: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee70400>,
 8: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee70630>,
 9: <pyimagesearch.trackableobject.TrackableObject object at 0x7f63fee70518>}
```

But I would like to see the information from object.

{1: 1, 18:01, 21:01
 2: 2, 15:34, 14:18
 ... 
}

Is any method for printing dictionary with information in objects instead of information about objects?

Answer (score 0):

Create the `__repr__` method. Just like you did `__str__`.

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` return the informal or nicely printable string representation of an object. It is used by `print` when you directly print the object. But when it is inside a list of a dict and that you print the container, what is used is the official representation which is defined by `__repr__`.

TL/DR: replace `__str__` with `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.objectID, self.timestart, self.timeend)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print the dictionary, `repr` is called on each element of the dictionary.
`repr` invokes `__repr__` method. So just add `__repr__` to class:

```py
class TrackableObject:
    # some methods here including __str__ ...
    __repr__ == __str__
```